# Laravel5.6 phpexcel package install error

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I'm trying to install phpexcel package in laravel5.6.26 via composer but it failed.Please find the attachment of issue i'm getting.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/150fv.png)

Comment: [phpexcel/phpexcel is deprecated](https://packagist.org/packages/phpexcel/phpexcel), its "successor" [phpoffice/phpexcel is abandoned](https://packagist.org/packages/phpexcel/phpexcel), why would you want to use them?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's better to include error messages, etc. as text rather than images.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing Laravel Excel via composer as showed [here](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines to your composer.json

```
"repositories": [
      {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packagist.org"
      },
      { "packagist": false }
    ]
```